# Spring Data MongoDB $where is not allowed in this context

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to make a Mongo criteria where the search value must be equal to `FIELD1 + "-" + FIELD2`:
What I've tried:

```
Criteria.where("$where").is("this." + SOFTWARE_NAME + " + '-' + this." + SOFTWARE_VERSION " ==  '" + value + "'");
```

But when I run a query with that criteria then I'm getting this exception:

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException:
> Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): '$where is not allowed in this
> context' on server hostname:17091. The full
> response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1614185267, "i":
> 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "$where is not allowed in this context",
> "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"

Even if I change the criteria to `"this." + SOFTWARE_NAME + " == this." + SOFTWARE_NAME` still the same exception is returned. I've seen many answers with a criteria that uses `where("$where")` so why it doesn't work for me?

When I run that query in Mongo directly:

```
{"$where" : "this.softwareName + '-' + this.softwareVersion == 'software-1.0.2'"}
```

then everything works perfectly fine.

EDIT

The query in the logs looks like this:

> "loggerName":"org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate","message":"Executing
> count: { "$where" : "this.softwareName + '-' + this.softwareVersion
> ==  'software-1.0.2'"} in collection ...

Comment: Work out what the constructed query is, update question with findings.

Comment: @D.SM Question updated.

Comment: So what query is being sent to the database? You showed something that only exists, and makes sense, in your application.

Comment: @D.SM I put the only query I could find in the debug logs.

Comment: Have you tried using a `BasicQuery` to define that type of query. Plus `$where` is not applicable in all scenarios. The error indicates a count query, that is run via an aggregation. Does it work using the native driver library (`collection.countDocuments(filter)`)?